# Grails - Date 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, grails

I need to be able to put, in a bad way, my variable "lastupdate" 0000: 00: 00 00:00:00, but I do not know how to do it since being a date gives me an error

```
class Dialernumbers {
    Integer campaign
    Date lastupdate

    static mapping = {
                    id column: "id", type:"long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'increment'
                        version false
                    }

       static constraints = {
                    lastupdate nulleable: true
                    }

}
```

Comment: date object requires a valid date 00/00/00 is invalid and therefore not allowed - the fact you have made it nullable:true means by setting the value to be null you could in effect treat it as 00/00/00 ? so if null that way otherwise a real date ? also be aware lastUpdated ending with `d` is auto managed by the framework - so that may be more difficult to manage manually -

Comment: @Vahid Hello! Thanks for answering! ... I need to be able to put the date in that format since it is required by Issabel - Asterisk for its correct operation :(

Comment: in that case you may have to declare the date as a string which you parse back each time you need a date since date by default goes http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java `Date represents a specific instance  in time`. So in short it has to be a valid date - but you could have `String lastupdate` instead which can be a date format of what ever and also store 00/00/00  you then follow this by a `getter` in that class like `Date getMyLastUpdate() { if (this.lastUpdate != '00/00/00') { return new Date(this.lastUpdate).parse('dd/MM/yyyy') } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issabel - Asterisk sounds like a co worker :) anyhow what I suggest is you don't do any of above  instead do this create another map inside the class

```
class Dialernumbers {
    Integer campaign
    Date lastupdate

    static mapping = {
                    id column: "id", type:"long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'increment'
                        version false
                    }


       Map loadValues() { 
           Map m =[:]
           m.campaign=this.campaign
           m.lastUpdate=this.lastUpdate ? this.lastUpdate : '00/00/00'

           return m
       }
       static constraints = {
          lastupdate nullable: true
       }

}
```

Now when you want to call class for `Issabel - Asterisk` you call

```
Dialernumbers dl = Dialernumbers.get(1L)
Issabel.dateValue = dl.loadValues().lastUpdate 

//Map values  = dl.loadValues()
//Issabel.dateValue = values.lastUpdate
```

This way you keep something that is a date field as a date field so it is then available for Hibernate and db queries just like a date and is also nullable in which case is returned in a specific format for your current requirements using loadValues and could be altered to another method for something else
`nullable` NOT `nulleable`